# Can juice have a higher sugar content after packaging?

Tags: food

It seems like the orange juice thats been sitting in the fridge for awhile always tastes sweeter than the juice just brought from the grocery store.

Can juice ripen in the container ? By that I mean, the concentration of fructose and other sugars increases.

I remember learning in Bio class that fruit releases a chemical that causes nearby fruit to also ripen faster. I'm not sure of the source of this chemical but my question leads me to believe that it is in the juice itself.